# Linear (in)dependence of distinct nonzero exponential polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

It is well-known that distinct exponential functions are linearly independent. What is known about the linear (in)dependence of the set of terms of an exponential polynomial? By exponential polynomial I mean a finite sum of terms of the form p_i(x) e^{a_i x} where each p_i is a polynomial. Here the exponential functions should be distinct, so the a_i are distinct; also the polynomials should be nonzero (that is, not identically zero). Under these conditions, is the set of functions p_1(x) e^{a_1 x}, ... , p_n(x) e^{a_n x} linearly independent?

Comment: Dear Bruce, this is true also for generalized exponenential functions  and generalized polynomials. I will given references and the ideas tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. A proof for a more general resulting can be foundation in

http://scholar.google.at/scholar_url?url=https://www.degruyter.com/downloadpdf/j/dema.2008.41.issue-3/dema-2013-0091/dema-2013-0091.xml&hl=en&sa=X&scisig=AAGBfm0VysxlFjgoiWZgO1rxRweNaSSa4Q&nossl=1&oi=scholarr

*Edit (2020-03-25):* The link above ist broken. Take the following one.
[Demonstration mathematica](https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/dema/41/3/article-p589.xml)